# JAVA - return two possible object types

Tags: java

I need to return two possible types of objects, depending on the functionality.

```
public ? returnBooleanOrString(){
    if(validation)
            return "String";
        else
            return false;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's possible, but very likely not the best option to the actual problem you are facing. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please add more context to your question.

Comment: Maybe you want to return `null` and use the type `String` as the return value. Or you use `Optional<String>` as the return type (if that works for you).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```java
public Object returnBooleanOrString() {
    if(validation)
            return "String";
        else
            return false;
}
```

Comment: Technically correct but definitely poor advice and almost certainly not what the OP *actually* means to do.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo yes this is not the best without context. But it works and pretty simple.

Answer (score 5):

The quick and dirty answer to your question is to return the greatest-lower-bound of the two types, i.e. the most specific common superclass. For `String` and `Boolean`, that's `Object`.

```
public Object returnBooleanOrString(){
  if(validation)
    return "String";
  else
    return false;
}
```

But hold on, this is almost certainly not what you want.

If you're coming from a dynamic language, you need to start thinking about types. Types are promises that you're making to the caller. If you return `Object`, you're promising "I'll return a thing that exists" with no further information. What you need to do is ask yourself what you intend that callers *do* with this information. `String` and `Boolean` have nothing in common, except for things that *all* objects have in common.

If you intend that the caller check whether the thing is truthy, and that's the only thing you care about, then simply return a Boolean

```
public boolean returnBooleanOrString() {
  if (validation)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

If you intend to return an "optional" value (I.e. the value may or may not exist, then you want [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

```
public Optional<String> returnBooleanOrString() {
  if (validation)
    return Optional.of("String");
  else
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Now the caller is forced to check whether the value existed before trying to do `String` operations on it. We've regained type safety.

If you intend to communicate more complicated information, consider making your own inheritance hierarchy.

```
public interface MyReturnType {
  public void someOperation();
}

public class Success implements MyReturnType {
  public String value;
  public Success(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  public void someOperation() { ... }
}

public class Failure implements MyReturnType {
  public boolean value;
  public Failure(boolean value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  public void someOperation() { ... }
}

public MyReturnType returnBooleanOrString() {
  if(validation)
    return new Success("String");
  else
    return new Failure(false);
}
```

Then you can restrict your interface to whatever operations make sense to do on your string-Boolean hybrid value.